# Can a Busy Beaver have duplicate transitions

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines

Is there any evidence or proof that a Turing machine that is a Busy Beaver champion cannot have a state where both transitions are identical? For example, suppose state C has transitions 1RA for input 0 and 1RA for input 1. Intuitively it seems like this can't be a good use of a state and the machine will be suboptimal (if finite), but I've never seen anyone address the idea of immediately discarding such machines.

Comment: I've removed the "large cardinals" tag since I doesn't seem related to the question.

Comment: What is the definition of busy beaver?

Comment: I'll like wikipedia explain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver

Comment: I infer that Busy Beaver implies a greedy algorithm.